# google display network HTTP referrer

Tags: google-ads-api, referrer

Is there any way to know that a visitor arrived on my site from clicking a google display ad, just from the HTTP logs - with the referrer header? I wan't to cross check google analytics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure AdWords to add the "network" property to your url tracking template. Something like this:

> {unescapedlpurl}?gad_network={network}

The value of gad_network in your url will be 'd' for Display Network.

See [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6076199?hl=en-GB) for editing the template.

There are other properties you can use. There's a list buried in [this](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447) this page.